# How can bind change of object data instantly in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, web-frontend

```
<div
   v-if="!item.editNickname"
   @click="item.editNickname=true, item.tmpNickname=item.nickname"
   >{{item.nickname}}</div>
    <v-text-field
      v-model="item.tmpNickname"
      v-if="item.editNickname||!item.nickname"
      outlined
      dense
      hide-details
      single-line
      v-on:keyup.enter="saveNickname(item)"
    />
```

Here is my code.
I want to edit nickname in data table.
If user click nickname(div), text field will show up.
But this code cannot bind instantly(Actually value is binded correct, but UI is not react).
Can I make UI react without other action?

=====================================================
+INFO
This code block is in 'v-data-table' which basic component of vuetify.
The item is an Object.

Comment: try to replace `,` by `;` in `@click="item.editNickname=true, item.tmpNickname=item.nickname"`

Comment: Thanks I try this way but it works same as before.

Comment: What do you mean by UI is not react?

Comment: In my intention, when I click 'div' the text field will shown. But now, not.
The value(item.editNickname) is changed but UI isn't.

Comment: Is `tmpNickname` already an existing property of your data?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below, I'm thinking `tmpNickname` is not one of the property that you are binding to the data table. See below for the sample code.

You can find the working code [here](https://codepen.io/sowmyadharg/pen/abNZRxz?editors=1010)

Template Code:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:item.nickname="{ item }">        
        <div v-if="!item.editable" @click="item.editable = true; item['tmpnickname'] = item.nickname">{{ item.nickname }}</div>
        <v-text-field
      v-model="item['tmpnickname']"
      v-if="item.editable"
      outlined
      dense
      hide-details
      single-line
      v-on:keyup.enter="saveNickname(item)"
    />
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Script Code:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Col 1',
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Nick name', value: 'nickname' }
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Row 1',
          nickname: 'Name 1',
          editable: false
        },
        {
          name: 'Row 2',
          nickname: 'Name 2',
          editable: false
        },
        {
          name: 'Row 3',
          nickname: 'Name 3',
          editable: false
        }
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveNickname (item) {
      item.editable = false;
      item.nickname = item.tmpnickname;
    }
  },
})
```